# Accessing constants defined in Kotlin in java class

Tags: android, kotlin

***I have defined some constants in kotlin***

```
object Keys {
    const val SPLASH_DURATION : Long = 5000

    const val READ_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
    const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
    const val WRITE_TIMEOUT : Int = 200

    var BASE_URL = BuildConfig.SERVER_KEY
}
```

- If I try to access BASE_URL in a Java class as `Keys.BASE_URL`. I get
  the error, It has private access.
- How to resolve this. Should I need to declare constants differently
  in kotlin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [**`Companion Objects`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

- An object declaration inside a class can be marked with the `companion` keyword:

Try this way

```
class Keys {

    companion object {
        const val SPLASH_DURATION : Long = 5000
        const val READ_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
        const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
        const val WRITE_TIMEOUT : Int = 200

    }
}
```

Now you can access your `const` variable like this

```
Keys.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
```

> Second Way

```
object Keys {
    const val SPLASH_DURATION: Long = 5000
    const val READ_TIMEOUT: Int = 200
    const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: Int = 200
    const val WRITE_TIMEOUT: Int = 200
}
```

Now you can access your `const` variable like this

```
Keys.SPLASH_DURATION;
```

Answer (score 4):

**How to solve:**

Add the `@JvmField`

**Example:**

```
object Keys {
    const val SPLASH_DURATION : Long = 5000

    const val READ_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
    const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
    const val WRITE_TIMEOUT : Int = 200

    @JvmField
    var BASE_URL = BuildConfig.SERVER_KEY
}
```

**Why**

1. Use @JvmField annotation on a public field in the object to tell the compiler to not generate any getter or setter
2. Expose it as a static field in the class

[See the kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can just create one **constants file** like above screenshot.

And define your constant value like this without making any companion Objects and access it through out your projects.

your constant values:-

```
const val SPLASH_DURATION : Long = 5000
const val READ_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
const val WRITE_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
```

And if you want to make companion Object than you can also do it in **KOTLIN**

for eg--

```
 class Keys {

   companion object {

       const val SPLASH_DURATION : Long = 5000
        const val READ_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
        const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : Int = 200
        const val WRITE_TIMEOUT : Int = 200

    }
}
```

and fetch it like this--

```
Keys.READ_TIMEOUT
```